# Triggered click vs. toggle for mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, toggle

I have a function that toggles a td cell toggles from highlighted to not highlighted based on mouse events.  This works well.

A checkbox triggered click action happens at the same time.  However, it seems like the triggered click is more sensitive than the toggle event. Sometimes the checkbox flickers on/off when the mouse is down over the td cell...leading to the highlighting and checkboxes to be out of sync sometimes.

How would be best to make the toggleclass and triggered click be in sync?

```
$(function () {
        var isMouseDown = false,isHighlighted;

      $("#tablegrid").on('mousedown', 'td.nohighlight', function() {
            isMouseDown = true;
            $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
            isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
            var checkBoxes = $(this).find('.dosearchescheckbox :checkbox').trigger('click');
            return false; // prevent text selection
          })

      $("#tablegrid").on('mouseover', 'td.nohighlight', function() {
            if (isMouseDown) {
              $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
              var checkBoxes = $(this).find('.dosearchescheckbox :checkbox').trigger('click');     
            }
          })
      $("#tablegrid").bind('selectstart', 'td.nohighlight', function() {    
            return false;
          })

      $(document)
        .mouseup(function () {
          isMouseDown = false;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the second parameter `isHighlighted` is always true on `mouseover`, `highlighted` class will always be added, while checkbox is still toggled.

So you can just call

```
$(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
// Instead of
// $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
```

See [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$( "#foo" ).toggleClass( className, addOrRemove );
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ( addOrRemove ) {
  $( "#foo" ).addClass( className );
} else {
  $( "#foo" ).removeClass( className );
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked.  The checkbox and coloring are all lined up.  Only small issue is now mousedown and hovering seems very sensitive (i.e., the box and checkboxes flicker a lot when mousedown over the box).  Though can cover that in separate question...